# Why are these DIVs overlapping and blocking links?

Tags: html, blocking, overlapping

When viewing [this page](http://vivomanchester.com/) at a width 767px, none of the links work. It appears to be blocked by an overlapping div, but I can't work out why.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the div style to

```
 div{
   overflow:auto;

  }
```

Comment: Though this is a good solution, it can be quite broad and create possible unwanted behaviors in the future. `div.features-var-three > div.container > div.row > div.col-lg-12 { overflow: auto; }` this code as it is will address the issue for that container specificallly.